# Missing packages from GNU Emacs

Tags: emacs, package

I’m been wanting to install a number of new packages for Emacs. mmm-mode, multi-web-mode, and smart-tab-mode are a few examples. But I don’t seem to be able to find them when I run

```
M-x package-list-packages
```

I have this in my `.emacs` file:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/"))
(package-initialize)
```

And when I run `package-list-packages` I can see that it contacts all those different hosts. I use `C-s` to search for them, they aren’t there. What am I doing wrong?

My Emacs version is displayed as: Version 24.2 (9.0)

Comment: The URL for MELPA is too short. It should be `http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL for Melpa was too short: it should be `http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/`

Answer (score 0):

You've mixed up the order. It goes like this:

```
(package-initialize)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
```

Comment: Try with `emacs -q`. Paste the code into `*scratch*` and eval one by one. That works for me

Comment: The hosts are being added you know (as OP states). When I describe the variable it has all the hosts in it. But packages are still missing. `(package-initialize)` returns `t`

Comment: Original post adjusted to give version (24.2)

Comment: What's your system? One more thing that you can try is to build Emacs from source.
Just to make sure that no libraries are missing.

Comment: x86_64 MacBook Pro running OS X 10.8.5. The emacs I’m using is the standard one I got from the website

Comment: Try to eval this:
`(package--with-work-buffer "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/" "archive-contents" (read buffer))`
It's supposed to give a list of packages.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39191/discussion-between-ollie-saunders-and-abo-abo)

Answer (score 0):

The ELPA/package system is a relatively new addition to Emacs. It is far from the case that all libraries are available as packages, but similarly it is not necessary for a library to *be* packaged in order to use it with Emacs.

If a library you wish to use is unavailable through any of the package repositories, simply follow the installation/usage instructions which (generally) can be found in the accompanying documentation for the library (either in the .el file's commentary, or as a separate file).

(You will at minimum need to ensure that the files are located in a directory which is in Emacs' load-path, but the exact details thereafter will vary depending upon the purpose of the library in question.)

Comment: OK well let’s take smart-tags-mode for example. http://www.emacswiki.org/SmartTabs states: `This code is now available as an Emacs minor mode through the MELPA package smart-tabs-mode and can be installed through the Emacs package manager. You can add MELPA to your package archive list with:

    (add-to-list 'package-archives ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))`